# Jetpack Compose: Notify changes in StateFlow

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow

I have a view model that gets search query data string every time a user enter a text in my text field in the Top App Bar.

The view model is as follows:

ViewModel.kt

```
class ServicesViewModel(
    private val offlineServiceRepository:ServiceRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private var searchQuery = mutableStateOf("")

    val servicesUiState: StateFlow<ServicesUiState> = offlineServiceRepository.search(searchQuery.value).map {

        Log.i("SEARCHVALUE", "UPDATE SF: ${searchQuery.value}")
        ServicesUiState.Success(it)
    }
        .stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(TIMEOUT_MILLIS),
            initialValue = ServicesUiState.Loading
        )


fun updateSearchQuery(query: String){
    searchQuery.value = query
    Log.i("SEARCHVALUE", "SQ: ${searchQuery.value}")
}
```

Then in my screen:

```
@Composable
fun ScreenServices(
    viewModel: ServicesViewModel,
    retryAction: () -> Unit,
    navigateToPreCall: (service: Service) -> Unit,
    searchBarValue: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {

    val servicesUiState by viewModel.servicesUiState.collectAsState()

    viewModel.updateSearchQuery(searchBarValue)

    when (servicesUiState) {
        is ServicesUiState.Loading -> LoadingScreen(modifier)
        is ServicesUiState.Success -> ServicesList((servicesUiState as ServicesUiState.Success).services, navigateToPreCall, modifier)
        is ServicesUiState.Error -> ErrorScreen(retryAction, modifier)
    }
}
```

The `searchBarValue` is being sent successfully from my UI screen to the viewModel every time the user types a new text and the `searchQuery` variable is updated accordingly. However the `servicesUiState` isn't getting the updated `searchQuery.value` and hence the list is not being updated on my UI.

Can someone help out on how i can pass the `searchQuery` variable to my `servicesUiState` `StateFlow` variable in my view model ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(Mutable)State` is a value holder class that could be observed for changes and comes with jetpack compose. It is similar to kotlin `Flow`. When you use it in a `@Composable` function, it will be automatically observed and your `@Composable` function will be recomposed on every change. You are not using it in a composable function, so you have to observe it yourself. One way to do that would be using [`snapshotFlow`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/14b9044e2fae5d88e2602db8f519d7aacfdba49d:compose/runtime/runtime/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/SnapshotFlow.kt;l=110) function to convert it to `Flow`:

```
private val searchQueryFlow = snapshotFlow { searchQuery.value }
val serviceUiState = searchQueryFlow.map { query ->
    offlineServiceRepository.search(query)
}.map { ... }
```

In your case though, it will be better to use `MutableStateFlow` instead, using `MutableState` here doesn't make much sense.